# Title text for own answer delete hyperlinks is confusing

Tags: discussion, user-interface, hyperlinks, usability

The title for the **delete** hyperlink on my own answers says **vote to remove this post**. I think this is confusing because it implies that other people can also vote to delete my answer, which I don't believe is the case.

My understanding is that when I click the link the answer is soft deleted and can probably by pruned by moderators at their leisure, but that's just implementation that as an end user I really don't care about.

Similarly, for **undelete** it says **vote to restore this post**. Why the use of the word *vote*?

Answer (score 1):

It's The Power of One, for you can Choose Your Own Adventure. But on this ride, you're Kevin Costner and for some reason the swing of the election rests upon your single vote.

And so it is with your own posts (excluding questions set by you that have upvoted answers) that you can cast a more powerful vote action to delete or undelete your answer. One is all it takes in this election season.

Also, you're playing baseball again.

Comment: So you're saying a monarchy is really a democracy where only one vote matters.

Comment: BTW, random - best. gravatar. ever.

Comment: Wow, @Jon B, that's almost quotably poetic.