# What eligibility is needed for vote in election

Tags: discussion, election, election-page

Is there any criteria for voting in any phase of election ? If yes then What eligibility is needed  for vote in election to vote in any or every phase.

Comment: There's also some useful information here, though some of it is out-dated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35670/clarifications-requested-on-the-moderator-election-process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=primary) and [Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=election) tabs, and look at the right side bar.  Among other things, it says that anyone with 150 reputation can participate.

Comment: Is this 150 reputation is eligible for every phase of election?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: The current FAQ states 150, so I guess this has changed.