# Eligibility requirements for Stack Overflow moderator elections

Tags: discussion, election, rep-requirement

There is no single place where SO users can check the requirements necessary to nominate oneself to a moderator elections.

There is a **formal** description of the requirements: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/51439/users-eligible-for-2011-stack-overflow-moderator-elections

But I think they should be summarized somewhere together in a more human-friendly way (i don't mean a programmer).

1. Reputation should be greater than 3000
2. Should have **all** of the following badges:

- Civic Duty
- Strunk & White
- Deputy
- Convention
- Yearling

Did I miss something?

Comment: The query itself is not that reliable, for example I meet all of the requirements but the data dump is old. I received the Deputy badge recently and that's not reflected in the current version of the data.

Comment: That is why it would be nice to have these requirements gathered in one place.

Comment: I agree, I was not arguing with you, I was adding to your argument.

Comment: Also some interesting (but outdated) information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35583/nominations-new-stack-overflow-moderator

Comment: Nice idea. Can you augment the query to exclude current moderators?

Comment: Yearling isn't a requirement anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/election/3 - It's documented when an election is in progress.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill: moderator status is permanent. So that none of current moderators need to be ever reelected.

Comment: Yes. But your query result includes the current moderators in the results. I'm asking if you could change the query so they would *not* be included; it would make the returned list shorter.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill: i cannot, i am not related to SO hosting.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were the author of that query, but now I see that you are not.

Comment: From what I've seen, they post the requirements every election.

Comment: @JimmyPena: yep, but you don't have much time to prepare in that situation.

Comment: There have been discussions about candidates shoring up their stats when they find out what the requirements are.  That shouldn't be how it works; if you meet a requirement, it should be because you've been helpful all along, not because you suddenly became interested in helping because you want to qualify for an election.

Comment: Sigh. More arbitrary segregation. I would have entered myself in the SO nominations to "fight the system" and open tons of closed questions. This site has devolved into some weird fiefdom that people are more interested in lording over users and instilling rules than having meaningful input from the **actual** community.

Comment: @Chris I'm against any and all restrictions for mod nominations - let the community sort things out through voting. Requiring badges and rep is silly. But BS like this about "fiefdoms" and "actual" communities (as if the people who invest the most time here somehow aren't part of the "actual" community)  isn't really helping the agenda.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've had numerous developers all agree with me that the bureaucracy SO seems to have elevated as a key "feature" has starkly driven them away. These are the types of developers you want SO to welcome. I'm just one of the only people that cares enough to try to change this, but clearly all dissenters must be silenced. Just as it happens with all kingdoms, shoot the person who doesn't agree with the royalty. And my statement about actual community is not BS, when you have questions with dozens or HUNDREDS of users input get closed as "not constructive" **THAT is BS**.

Comment: @Chris `These are the types of developers you want SO to welcome.` what makes you think that's who I want SO to welcome? My opposition to badge requirements in mod elections?

Comment: `you` as in Stackoverflow as a whole. The fact you personally are making pedantic arguments about who should be wanted as a community member just really puts the nail in the coffin as to why so many high quality developers have just abandoned SO.

Comment: @Chris well, it still seems to be doing okay in that department (high quality developers), and is the #1 resource on programming Q&A. Have you ever considered the possibility that what you call "bureaucracy", for all its faults, is part of the reason for that? I agree way too much stuff is getting closed way too harshly these days, but as said, your wild generalizations and rhetoric aren't really contributing anything useful to the discussion.

Comment: You missed that (1) you must have not been suspended in the past year and (2) yearling is ***NOT*** a required badge for running for moderator.

Comment: @John This is a very old question. They didn't "miss" anything - the requirements have just changed a bit over time. This likely hasn't been updated because we just publish all the requirements directly on the election page now, and they're also different per-site.