# Determining who is a moderator in data explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump

As far as I can tell, there's no indication in the data dumps accessible in Data Explorer as to whether a particular user is a diamond moderator or not. This would certainly be a useful thing to know (for example, [culling current moderators from the results of an eligibility query.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141099/eligibility-requirements-for-stack-overflow-moderator-elections)) My tripartate question is thus

1. Am I wrong and there *is* some way to determine diamond moderator status in a query?
2. If there isn't, can we get that added?
3. I have a feeling the answer to #2 may be *no*, and it may have been decided to leave the information out deliberately. if that's the case, is there a publicly-accessible explanation of the reasoning behind this?

Comment: This would then also need start and end dates? (Possibly multiple if a moderator has been away for a while.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is something that is needed in the data dumps/data explorer.  For *any* given site, the number of moderators is *very* low (Stack Overflow currently has the highest at 15).

Given that our identities are *not* secret, it's not difficult to get our user ids and filter those out of the users for any queries that you might run.

You can find the current Stack Overflow moderators on the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) (for other Stack Exchange sites, it's simply `http://<site>.stackexchange.com/about`).