# What are the criteria for moderator nomination?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, election, moderators, nominations

On the community moderator election [page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), I see three sets of requirements, in different places.

The main body of text says

> For the Stack Overflow election, an **eligible candidate for the
> election** must have all of the following badges:
>
> - **Civic Duty**
> - **Strunk & White**
> - **Deputy**
> - **Convention**

At the bottom,

> You need all of the following badges to nominate yourself as a candidate: **Strunk & White, Civic Duty, Deputy, and Convention**.

Then off to the side,

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than **3,000 reputation** may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.

I'm not sure if the first one refers to a different event or phase ("election" vs. "nomination"), but the last two certainly seem (to me) to be at odds.

Does someone need reputation, badges, or both to be nominated?

---

**This is not a duplicate** of [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work), which mentions *nothing about 3,000 reputation*.

If anything, this is a duplicate of (currently unanswered) [Eligibility requirements for Stack Overflow moderator elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141099/eligibility-requirements-for-stack-overflow-moderator-elections?rq=1).

Comment: I guess it's both... but perhaps the former is checked only at election time. Just like Schwarzenegger could probably *run* for President, but never actually take office

Comment: @Pëkka, I might think so...but the second statement seems to say otherwise.

Comment: Ah, I see. But it's arguably minor -> bottom line: if you want to run, you need those badges.

Comment: Two of your bullets "Civic" and "Duty" are actually a single badge "Civic Duty".

Comment: @Pëkka, so you think it is badges *and* points?

Comment: @Paul yup, definitely. The points used to be a hard limit and the badges were manually checked later int he process... not sure how it works these days

Comment: Did you try to nominate yourself? Did the system let you start?